# calling magento in android

Tags: android, magento, soap, ksoap2

I'm using ksoap2 Android library to call Magento api trough SOAP. Login method (to get sessionId) works fine, but Call method won't accept additional arguments. Call method has three parameters:
call(sessionId, resourcePath,array arguments). resourcePath I want to call is customer.list and additional paramteters is filter(email). Api documentation is [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.list.html).

```
Hashtable<String, String> hashtable = new Hashtable<String, String>();
hashtable.put("email", "myemail");

SoapObject request = new SoapObject("urn:Magento", "call");
request.addProperty("resourcePath", "customer.list");
request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
request.addProperty("args", hashtable);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
(new MarshalHashtable()).register(envelope);
envelope.dotNet = false;
envelope.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
envelope.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
transport.debug = true;
transport.call("", envelope);
```

With this code i successfully get list of customers, but email filter won't apply.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, i would like to request u that plz share the answer. i am trouble in magneto SOAP v1 integration in android

Comment: Hi. We switched to XMLRPC from SOAP so I can't help you...sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Change and Add the following code as given below

```
(new MarshalHashtable()).register(envelope);
        Hashtable<String, String> hashtable = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        hashtable.put("email", "myemail");
 Vector<Hashtable<String, String>>aar2=new Vector<Hashtable<String, String>>();
        aar2.add(hashtable);
        parameter.addProperty("args", aar2);
```

Answer (score 0):

**hey it issue with filter**

```
$filters = array(array('email' => array('eq'=>'myemail'))
);
```

call customer list like

```
$result = $client->call($session, 'customer.list', $filters);
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I need it with Java. Ksoap2 has poor documentation.